# how to create textnode in CKEditor

Tags: dom, ckeditor

I am not able to make text node in CKEditor.
please help me.I have tried

```
var textNode = editor.document.text('myText');
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Without knowing what you intend to do with one I can only say this

```
var ele = new CKEDITOR.dom.element("p", CKEDITOR.instances.editor1.document);
```

Source: [docs](http://docs.cksource.com/ckeditor_api/symbols/CKEDITOR.dom.element.html#constructor)